# How to return a value into a mobx computed using jquery's $.ajax via callback?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobx

In my project I have the following mobx store:

```js
class AvailabilityCallendar {
  @observable selected_date = new Date();
  @observable max_persons = 2;
  @observable loading = false;

  @computed get availableDates() {
    $.ajax({
      url:
        createUrl('/calendar/availability') +
        'persons=' +
        this.max_persons +
        '&' +
        selected_date.format('yy-m-d'),
      type: 'GET',
      beforeSend: function () {
        this.loading = true;
      },
      success: function (data) {
        // return value here
      },
      fail: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        this.loading = false;
        console.error('Error: ' + errorThrown + ', Status: ' + textStatus);
      },
    });
  }
}
```

But in this case Idk how I can return the value from success ajax callback.
Do you know how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can return `Promise` here but I won't recommend it because you are breaking the rules of computed values.

Computed should not have side effects nor they should update other observable values.

Answer (score 0):

`computed` values of mobx are a "view" over other observable element. It must be a **sync** operation, therefore your implementation is not correct.

What you need to to is a simple `observable` & an async method which will update its value.

```js
// pseudo code

class AvailabilityCallendar {
  @observable selected_date = new Date();
  @observable max_persons = 2;
  @observable loading = false;
  @observable availableDate = null; // initial value, it may be any valid js value.

  async getAvailableDate() {
    $.ajax({
      url:
        createUrl('/calendar/availability') +
        'persons=' +
        this.max_persons +
        '&' +
        selected_date.format('yy-m-d'),
      type: 'GET',
      beforeSend: function () {
        this.loading = true;
      },
      success: function (data) {
        this.availableDate = data // this assignment will trigger all the observers of the observable field.
      },
      fail: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        this.loading = false;
        console.error('Error: ' + errorThrown + ', Status: ' + textStatus);
      },
    });
  }
}
```

Then call `getAvailableDate()`

Comment: I think should be an mobx @action.